# GetX go to a new layout/screen, and hide the bottom navigation bar. the bottom nav still show up when i do get.ofnamed

Tags: flutter, dart, get, flutter-getx

i having a bottom navigation bar that look like this below

```dart
class BottomNavigationsBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationsBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavigationsBar> createState() => _BottomNavigationsBarState();
}

class _BottomNavigationsBarState extends State<BottomNavigationsBar> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final List _pages = [
    EcoHomePageView(),
    ChatCheckLogin(),
    EcoNotificationPageView(),
    UserCheckLogin(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _pages[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: ontap,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
              label: "Home",
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.message_outlined),
              label: "Chat",
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.message)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_outlined),
              label: "Home",
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.notifications)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
              label: "User",
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.person)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void ontap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

it works properly till when i need to go to new screen, using this code below

```dart
 onTap: () =>
     Get.toNamed(Routes.UPLOAD_PRODUCT),
```

but when i arrive at the other page. the bottom navigation bar still there. how can i directly go to other page leaving the bottom navigation bar behind??

this is the main.dart code

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final authC = Get.put(AuthController(), permanent: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
              body: BottomNavigationsBar(),
            ),
          );
        }
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: authC.firstInitialized(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) => SplashScreen(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you could use GetMaterialApp with getPages method. Add there all your pages(parent pages, like splash or home). If you don't want to use GetMaterialApp you should use MaterialApp with routes method. Why did you add future.delayed before your app? Your app should be initiated before any computations, or you'll get blank black screen. Work like this: init all data in splash screen and then open your home page. I really wondered that your code is working.

Comment: the future.delay was for the splashscreen that i read from native splashscreen package on pub.dev

Comment: You used Get.toNamed(Routes.UPLOAD_PRODUCT), where did you initiate your screens? To use toNamed you need to add named screens to routes method in material app.

Answer (score 0):

Use persistent_bottom_nav_bar for keep bottom navigation bar to all the screens.

https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32916763)

Comment: I'm using this and its not solving the problem when I use GetMaterialApp and Get.toNamed